# VS Code files.watcherExclude default setting is not effective with Nx

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening an Nx repo, I'm seeing this message when starting VS Code:

[image: VS Code watcher message]

Link: [Instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc)

In VS Code, the default setting for `files.watcherExclude` seems reasonable:

[image: VS Code watcher exclude setting]

However, it doesn't seem to be working as I'm still getting the message.

Is there a way to see what files are triggering this message so that I can exclude them?

For now, I'll do it the old-fashioned way by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

... and running `sudo sysctl -p`.

Comment: where exactly is `.nx/` located? and what if you change `**/node_modules/*/**` to `**/node_modules/**`?

Comment: `.nx` is in the workspace root.

Comment: Most of the entries in`node_modules` are dirs, so `**/node_modules/**` would only match 1 additional file that's in the root. I do still wonder why that isn't the default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for Nx projects, this is also needed under `files.watcherExclude`:

```
**/.nx/cache/*/**
```